# Umbraco XML cache how to see it?

Tags: caching, umbraco

I was given an existing Umbraco project wherein I saw almost codes are being cache, but I only know bit regarding caching.

On the project it has a class named "CacheManager" and full of methods with "ApplicationContext.Current.ApplicationCache.RuntimeCache.GetCacheItem", ".RequestCache", and any kinds of cache.

Now I wonder how can I see these caches, specially the keys because I saw this code:

```
public static T GetCacheItem<T>(string cacheKey)
{
    return ApplicationContext.Current.ApplicationCache.RuntimeCache.GetCacheItem<T>(cacheKey);
}
```

Is there any way I can see the list of cacheKey and its corresponding values? so I know what cacheKey to get? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Glimpse** (free, open-source → http://getglimpse.com/). It has Cache Tab which is showing the content of RuntimeCache (+ lot of other useful features helping to diagnose an app).